# Idiomatic way to define functionality for all primitive integer types

Tags: generics, rust, macros

I have a function defined for `i64` that returns an iterator over the number's digits.

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=50d20a4a02442549a2e2381e369d428e))

```
fn digits_of(num: i64) -> impl Iterator<Item = u8> {
    let num = num.abs();
    let nth_digit = move |exp| (num / 10_i64.pow(exp) % 10) as u8;
    let largest_exponent = (num as f64).log10() as u32;
    (0..=largest_exponent).into_iter().map(nth_digit).rev()
}

fn main() {
    for digit in digits_of(-8675309) {
        println!("{}", digit);
    }
}
```

I would like to somehow generalize this for all of the primitive integer types, but I cannot think of a good way to do this.

One solution would be to manually implement the function for every primitive, which would work, but would be a lot of copy-and-pasting.

Another (undesirable) solution would be to implement it only twice for `i128` and `u128`, where I could always cast a smaller type and invoke it the following way:

```
fn main() {
    let x: u8 = 10;
    for digit in digits_of(x as u128) {
        println!("{}", digit);
    }
}
```

I have tried to implement it using generics, where `T: Integer + Div + Rem` etc., but I can't cast the generic like I can with a primitive: `num as f64`

My inclination is that this may be possible with `macro_rules!` (perhaps using `expr` and `ty`), but I am quite new to macros in Rust. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: *I can't cast the generic like I can with a primitive* — Use `From` / `Into` / `num::NumCast` / `num::ToPrimitive` for this.

Comment: [The duplicates applied to your situation.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=879c1df96542567250ac5b31fe6376b3)

Comment: @Shepmaster, this is super helpful. Thank you!